# Core Data - Cascade delete in relationship not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

[image]

[image]

insertion code :

```
let dbObj: NSEntityDescription? = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CartTable", in: self.appDelegate.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext)

        if dbObj != nil {

            let myCartObj: CartTable = CartTable(entity: dbObj!, insertInto: self.appDelegate.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext)

            myCartObj.menuId = self.itemListDataResponseModel?.menuItemId
            myCartObj.menuName = self.itemListDataResponseModel?.menuItemName
            myCartObj.menuPrice = self.itemListDataResponseModel?.price
            //myCartObj.menuQuantity
            //myCartObj.menuTotalPrice
            myCartObj.userId = AppDataStoreManager.getUserDefault(KeyToReturnValye: "userId") as! String?
            myCartObj.imageUrl = self.itemListDataResponseModel?.imgPath
            myCartObj.desc = self.itemListDataResponseModel?.description
            myCartObj.locationId = AppDataStoreManager.getUserDefault(KeyToReturnValye: "locationId") as! String?
            myCartObj.locationName = AppDataStoreManager.getUserDefault(KeyToReturnValye: "locationName") as! String?
            myCartObj.vendorId = self.vendorObject?.vendorId
            myCartObj.vendorName = self.vendorObject?.vendorName

            self.appDelegate.coreDataStack.saveContext()
```

deletion code :

```
self.appDelegate.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext.delete(obj)
    self.appDelegate.coreDataStack.saveContext()
```

when i delete an item from cart table then all the related entries regarding to same menu id from carttablesidemenu item table must have to be deleted.
currently when i delete entry from carttable then it getting deleted but entries in carttable side menu not getting deleted that means relationship not working

Comment: How do you set the `rel_CartTableSideMenu` relationship?  Also, check the type: it's defined as to-one, but you say "when I delete an item from cart table then **all** the related entries ... from carttablesidemenu item table must have to be deleted" - which implies it should be to-many?

Comment: i also tried with it but nothing happening

Answer (score 0):

NSManagedObject automatically creates its accessors methods so we have to use that methods to maintain relationships.